# Customising a bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

completely new here and just wondering if anyone might be able to give me an answer to my question.

So this is an example of the navbar effect I am trying to implement:
http://www.autotrader.co.uk/

I know that bootstrap comes with the .navbar-fixed-top class however I can't seem to find anyone pulling off the function that www.autotrader.co.uk has. For example if you scroll down the page the nav will follow.

I can achieve this function with custom CSS & JavaScript however I get grid problems when I do this.

Is there a way in bootstrap to achieve that sticky effect when scrolled? I can only find solutions for pinning the nav to the top of the viewport. Can I also ask... if I develop outside the bootstrap container will that cause any issues? I'm thinking I could just develop outside the container and just media query the nav?

Any tips would be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: What is navbar-fixed-top not doing for you?

Comment: I need to have my logo above my navbar and when navbar-fixed-top is used it places the nav right at the top of the viewport I need the nav to sit under the logo. If you visit the site example and scroll down you will understand :)

Comment: have you looked into bootstrap affix feature. It you can use it to attach the navbar when the user scrolls to an offset set by yourself. I use it here. http://bootstrap-growl.remabledesigns.com/ You can than use css to hide the logo by default and reveal it when the navbar has the class `affix`

Comment: I can put a demo together for you on http://www.bootsnipp.com when I get back from my dogs grooming appointment if no one else beats me to it.

Comment: I've had try with that just now using the examples supplied. I can't seem to get a nice effect. If you take a look here at this super simple example: http://screencast.com/t/QAxAuPPATM5L

It just seems to jump and I can't seem to find any classes to change that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the affix way to do it.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/2t5WB/)

I added a little css to fade in/fade out the navbar-brand as well.  It's a nice effect if you wanted to have your logo at the top of the page and then add it to the navbar when it becomes fixed.

**CSS:**

```
.brand {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #ff0066;
    margin: 50px 0 25px;
}
.navbar-brand {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear;
    transition: opacity .5s linear;
}
.navbar {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}
nav.affix {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
nav.affix .navbar-brand {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="brand"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i> hearthealth.org</div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default affix-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="80" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-6">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button> 
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i> hearthealth.org</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
         <h2>some lorem ipsum for scrolling:</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p> 

<!-- Add enough text to be able to scroll -->

    </div>
</div>
```

As an alternative, you can use jQuery to add/remove the .navbar-fixed-top class.  Here's an example of that ([demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/eY8nQ/)):

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {  
    var scrollpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollpos > 80) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you that is just what I was looking for! :) I hope some others can learn from this also :) I hate to be picky but is there a way to stop sudden jump by the way? For example scroll it slowly and it suddenly jumps. I will have a play around anyway and see what I can do thanks!

Comment: Adjust the offset value.  I used 80px, but that might not be the right amount for your design. Just check what the height is of the element above the nav (or set it to a specific height) and use that value so that when the nav just "kisses" the top of the window it gets fixed in place.  You could also use some animation so that it gets animated into its fixed position.

Comment: To make the point, I just set both demos to 115, which was the height of the container before the navbar.  No more getting "sucked" into position.